# Terminating a process created using spawnv

Tags: process, termination

I'm not experienced with processes at all, but what I'm set to to should be really simple.
All I do is spawn a process like this:

```
int spawnId = spawnv(_P_NOWAIT,"wgetlocal.exe",my_env);
```

Now, what I want to do is kill this program after a certain time. However, the returned spawnId is not what I need when for instance calling `taskkill /PID [number] /F`.

I've tried using `otherId2 = GetWindowThreadProcessId((HWND)spawnId,OUT otherId1)` but again, neither `otherId1` or `otherId2` give the correct PID.

If anyone could help me witht his, I'd be vary thankfull.
Regards,
Roald

Answer (score 1):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zt1y878.aspx):

> The return value from an asynchronous `_spawnv` or `_wspawnv` (`_P_NOWAIT` or `_P_NOWAITO` specified for mode) is the process handle.

When you have a process handle, you can use [`TerminateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714.aspx).

Types of handles are not interchangeable. You cannot type-cast a process handle to `HWND` and have it suddenly be a window handle.